# How to use str_sub?

Tags: r, stringr

When I use `str_sub` to get the first 3, I get the result like this,

[image]

Actually, I want to get the first 3 digits,

[image]

like, 216-555-2549, I want to have 216, things like that.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your argument for `string =` does not need a `""`
try to change `string= "phone_number"` to `string = phone_number`